# How should "makeup" be written in BrEng?

Tags: british-english, orthography, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

By "makeup", I mean cosmetics, as in lipstick, foundation, eyeliner, etc. My assumption is that it should be written as "makeup", but others have suggested "make up" or "make-up".

In case there are any regional differences, I'm primarily interested in the most idiomatic written form in Britain/Ireland.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Which dictionaries or other sources have you consulted?

Comment: The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) is actually undecided between "the make up" (four hits that fit the bill) and "the makeup" (five). But it quite clearly rules out "the make-up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Brits use the hyphenated and single-word versions about equally often...

[image]

...but Americans have more decisively abandoned the hyphen...

[image]

In such usages the general trend is always *two words -> hyphenated -> single word*, so I've no doubt UK usage will catch up soon enough. As of right now I would say both forms are equally "valid" in BrE - but you may as well dump the hyphen now, since we all will eventually.